# Couldn't get correct answer from MySQL LIKE function

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a row which contains `'asa'` string in my MySQL database. Then I am trying to get result from query when input is like that `'asas2s'`
But I couldn't get result.

My query is like that:

```
SELECT * FROM mod WHERE course LIKE '%asa2s%'
```

Comment: '111' is not like '%111s1S%', so you are getting the correct answer....

Comment: Should work.  Check your data again.  Maybe some of the 1s are Ls or something like that.

Comment: 111s1S is like '%111%'

Comment: @JackWilliams: MySQL?

Comment: [*see difference in fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6e1ea/3)

Comment: @JackWilliams would return anything with a 1, s or S in it wouldn't it?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson. Yeah, i think you're right. How about this?  `SELECT * FROM modules WHERE code RLIKE '/^111/'`

Comment: @JackWilliams Not sure OPs requirement is a bit vague, that would be the equivalent of like '111%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, but it is slow query because the predicate is not SARGable.

```
SELECT * FROM mod WHERE 'asas2s' LIKE concat(course, '%')
```

Comment: Nice! Why is `concat` for column needed? :L

Comment: It is needed to generate search pattern.